# iTextpdf Java compatibility

Tags: java, oracle11g, itext, pdf-generation

I need to encrypt a pdf document and decided to use itext Version 5.4.0 for this, and everything went well for my local test on my machine(with JAVA 1.8.0), but now I need to move the work to an oracle database 11gR2, and when I load the jar files (iText and bouncycastle) I keep getting the same error: ORA-29534:referenced object could not be resolved. I'm using the `loadjava` command for this:

```
loadjava -u SYSTEM/SYS_PWD@SID -o -r -v -f -noverify -synonym -g public itextpdf-5.1.0.jar
```

I've tried using SYS as well, but still getting the same error code. 
I don't know if this has something to do with the JVM, the database uses JAVA 1.5.0.

I've searched about iText java requirements but couldn't found anything
useful, I'll be grateful with any help I can get.

Comment: Also, I'm currently using bouncycastle version 1.48

Comment: You say you *"decided to use itext Version 5.4.0"* but then you load `itextpdf-5.1.0.jar`. And if you start now with a project, you should use a current version. In case of itext 5 that is a 5.5.x with x > 10 currently...

Comment: I used both 5.1.0 and 5.4.0 iText versions and even I used an apache library for pdf (PDFBox) and still getting the same error, I don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upload, compile and use the libraries in the .jar files using the same command but with other parameter, and it compiled;  the command I used is :

```
loadjava -u SYS/[pwd]@[SID] -r -v -f -genmissing -s -grant public [file].jar
```

Hope this can help someone in need out there!